Creating sliced terrain from a TopoShaper generated Sketchup mesh, generated from ArcMap contours
One way to make terrain in Sketchup from contour lines is to use ArcMap to generate height contours, export them to Sketchup as .dwg files, then use the plugin TopoShaper to generate a terrain from that .dwg
Now here's the problem, the person I'm working with is inexperienced doing architectural modelling on a mesh geometry and would prefer a sliced terrain instead. There's a plugin called Slicer, which calls for Joint Push and Pull performed on the mesh terrain. Theoretically this should work but for some reason, using Slicer on my terrain only results in Sketchup crashing. I did a test by making a sphere. meshing it, then slicing it using Slicer and it worked, so I'm at a loss here right now, seeking for alternatives or fixes to this process.
